# how to put text around centered image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to accomplish something like this: [image]

The can't seem to emulate the one above where the centered image is being surrounded by texts. I've tried using floats but something is just lacking and I have no idea what.

And this is what I currently have:

[image]

here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/eqs6e1db/

```
section{
 text-align: center;
}

section p{
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-ms-column-count: 3;
-o-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
text-align: justify;
}

section article:first-child{
float: left;
}

section article:last-child{
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Basically, CSS isn't really ready to do this yet. CSS shapes are on the way but until they're ready for prime-time I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Is there any cheat that could accomplish this? I am having my internship and I am asked to convert some psd's to html template and this is one of them.

Comment: Not really..not with any flexibility. HTML hasn't caught up with "print" layouts yet. - [**Faking Float "Center"**](https://css-tricks.com/float-center/) is about the closest I've found. But I'd be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Well, guess I have to ask our designer if I can tweak the page a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Check [Text areas](http://codepen.io/collection/Dmrrad/) from user @web-tiki. I found it really nice.

Comment: @Renboy Ok this one got me going crazy! I've been trying for an hour!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can not achieve **really** your layout. But you can hack it a little bit.

For each column, you can set a spacer, a filler, and another spacer.

The first spacer reserves space from the top, just to push the filler to the required position. The filler really reserves the space. And the reamining spacer consumes the remaining space so that we go the other column.

You need to have a height set on the container

```css
.base {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}


.pushtop {
  background-color: rgba(200,0,0,0.2);
  width: 10px;
  height: 17%;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.pushbottom {
  background-color: rgba(200,0,0,0.2);
  width: 10px;
  height: calc(83% - 200px);
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.insert {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
.insertleft {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.insertcenter {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.insertright {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  width: 735px;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  width: 485px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 123px;
  top: 170px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="base">

<div class="pushtop"></div>
<div class="insert insertleft"></div>
<div class="pushbottom"></div>
<div class="pushtop"></div>
<div class="insert insertcenter"></div>
<div class="pushbottom"></div>
<div class="pushtop"></div>
<div class="insert insertright"></div>
<div class="pushbottom"></div>
<p>Another 4-storey structure will soon be under construction to add new classrooms and laboratories for the High School and Grade School.</p> 
 
<p> Part of the reason for this attention to the North Campus is to help FU’s marketing strategy for the high school in response to the implementation of the K to 12 Program.  First, we want to attract more enrollees. Second, we invest in the facilities in our aim to increase not just the quality of our education but to boost our enrollment capacity from 700 students to 1500 students. And of Course, thanks to our new solar panel installation, we will also be providing all the new classrooms with air conditioning for those sweltering months.</p> 

<p>Corporate Social Responsibility or CSR, as viewed by the University, should also have a significant space in the academe's achievements and obligations.</p>

<p>Estudio Damgo, for instance, is now on its third iteration of touching people's lives through sustainable and life-changing architecture. Its buildings and designs, since its first project in 2013, serve as prototype structures that cater to the various needs of society. The University sees Estudio Damgo as a catalyst for creating a transformed, more developed, and more meaningful way of living not just in Dumaguete but through out the Philippines. Read more about the current project here. (note to Entheos; link the word “here” to full Estudio Damgo article)</p>

    <p>In terms of agriculture, FU's Aquaponics sets the example in the use of completely natural and organic farming techniques, which enhance not only the environment's safety but boost farmers' production capabilities and livelihood as well. Aquaponics provides agriculturists the answer to sustainable food production and a sustainable ecosystem for both fish and plants. For more specifics on our organic farm click here. (Note to Entheos: Link the word “here” to full organic farming article)</p>

<p>A forest and wildlife protection program called “Ayungon Forest Reserve” has also been pushed by the College of Arts and Sciences in partnership with local government units and the Department of the Environment and Natural Resources (DENR). The program calls for protecting the natural resources of the Reserve from causes of declining population, degradation of wildlife habitat, deterioration of soil and river quality, and the cave’s carrying capacity.</p>
 
<p>The College of Business Administration (CBA), on the other hand, is seriously pursuing a strong “Entrepreneurship Program” that caters to all levels of participants from students to MSMEs (Micro, Small, Medium Enterprises). In fact, the CBA in partnership with DTI will soon launch an “Entrep Hub”—a one-stop business center for start-up entrepreneurs—during the University Expo in which high school students will compete for the best business plan. The prize will be an Incubation Program for the winning plan to become a real business.</p>
 
<p>The University Expo, formerly the Digital Expo, of the College of Computer studies is a major University event that showcases innovative technology. The annual event, which includes robotic challenges, quiz bowls, film festivals, etc., is an avenue for students from different academic institutions to participate in and learn from the latest IT breakthroughs.</p>

<p>Barangay constituents also have the opportunity to learn computer skills such as basic PC operations, Internet use, word processing, spreadsheet and presentation through the university's Computer Literacy Program for adopted barangays.</p>

<p>Moreover, “The Queue” coffee shop, run by the College of Hospitality Management ‘s Culinary Arts students, draws customers from in and outside the campus because of its delicious food and beverages.</p>
 

 
</div>
  </div>
```

Note that the filler and spacer elements should not be visible. I have given the a background and a width (in the case of the push elements) so that you can see how it works

Comment: I finally got it to work, I copied the column-count code in my text container instead of the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

CSS as it stands, cannot do this yet (reliably). However, there is in working, a CSS Shapes Module that can do this.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/898/Wrapping-Text-Around-A-Curved-Image-With-CSS-Shapes

Only supported in Chrome and Safari it seems:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own method to make your style image in centre of page so i made this following method

**note**: check this in you page here in demo it doesn't works

```css
         div{
                margin: 15px
            }
            p{
                float:left;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            .left{
                float:left;
                width:30%;
            }
            .centre{
                display: inline-block;
                width:30%;
            }
            .right{
                float:right;
                width:30%;
            }
            .right, .centre, .left p{
                text-align:justify
            }
```

```html
<div class="left">
            <p>Another 4-storey structure will soon be under construction to add new classrooms and laboratories for the High School and Grade School.</p> 
            <p>In terms of agriculture, FU's Aquaponics sets the example in the use of completely natural and organic farming techniques, which enhance not only the environment's safety but boost farmers' production capabilities and livelihood as well. Aquaponics provides agriculturists the answer to sustainable food production and a sustainable ecosystem for both fish and plants. For more specifics on our organic farm click here. (Note to Entheos: Link the word “here” to full organic farming article)</p>
            <p>Have you also heard of Greyhound Events and Tours? Well, it is Foundation University’s student-run functional travel agency that caters to the travel needs of both the FU community and outside clients.</p>
            <p>Integrating CSRs in the various programs is our chance to give back to the community as well as gain the respect of the members of the society, young and old. It also helps garner the public's appreciation for the importance of community involvement by producing tangible projects everybody can benefit from.</p>
            <p>Expanding the University’s Information Technology (IT) to meet the demands of a digital age is another factor in FU’s “micro” to “macro” plan. Aside from the existing iPad program, the University is determined to create digital classrooms that can be accessed by local towns like Bacong, Dauin and Zamboangita. There is also a movement to encourage students, even at the high school level, to learn useful skills such as computer programming so they can be competitive in an IT driven world.</p> 
            <p>On the infrastructure side, FU is also updating the “bare bones” of FUs communication network to fiber optic cables and high-end routers and equipment. You can read a comprehensive explanation of these updates in a separate article in this issue of CQ here.
                (Note to Entios: link the word “here” to full IT article)</p></div>
        <div class="centre">
            <p> Part of the reason for this attention to the North Campus is to help FU’s marketing strategy for the high school in response to the implementation of the K to 12 Program.  First, we want to attract more enrollees. Second, we invest in the facilities in our aim to increase not just the quality of our education but to boost our enrollment capacity from 700 students to 1500 students. And of Course, thanks to our new solar panel installation, we will also be providing all the new classrooms with air conditioning for those sweltering months.</p> 
            <p>Estudio Damgo, for instance, is now on its third iteration of touching people's lives through sustainable and life-changing architecture. Its buildings and designs, since its first project in 2013, serve as prototype structures that cater to the various needs of society. The University sees Estudio Damgo as a catalyst for creating a transformed, more developed, and more meaningful way of living not just in Dumaguete but through out the Philippines. Read more about the current project here. (note to Entheos; link the word “here” to full Estudio Damgo article)</p>
            <img src="http://animalia-life.com/data_images/cat/cat4.jpg" style="height:300px;width:100%;" alt="">
            <p>The College of Business Administration (CBA), on the other hand, is seriously pursuing a strong “Entrepreneurship Program” that caters to all levels of participants from students to MSMEs (Micro, Small, Medium Enterprises). In fact, the CBA in partnership with DTI will soon launch an “Entrep Hub”—a one-stop business center for start-up entrepreneurs—during the University Expo in which high school students will compete for the best business plan. The prize will be an Incubation Program for the winning plan to become a real business.</p>
            <p>The University Expo, formerly the Digital Expo, of the College of Computer studies is a major University event that showcases innovative technology. The annual event, which includes robotic challenges, quiz bowls, film festivals, etc., is an avenue for students from different academic institutions to participate in and learn from the latest IT breakthroughs.</p>
            <p>Aside from all the projects mentioned above, our overview of the 2015 Master Plan wouldn’t be complete if we didn’t tell you about one more core component.</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Corporate Social Responsibility or CSR, as viewed by the University, should also have a significant space in the academe's achievements and obligations.</p>
            <p>A forest and wildlife protection program called “Ayungon Forest Reserve” has also been pushed by the College of Arts and Sciences in partnership with local government units and the Department of the Environment and Natural Resources (DENR). The program calls for protecting the natural resources of the Reserve from causes of declining population, degradation of wildlife habitat, deterioration of soil and river quality, and the cave’s carrying capacity.</p>
            <p>Barangay constituents also have the opportunity to learn computer skills such as basic PC operations, Internet use, word processing, spreadsheet and presentation through the university's Computer Literacy Program for adopted barangays.</p>
            <p>Moreover, “The Queue” coffee shop, run by the College of Hospitality Management ‘s Culinary Arts students, draws customers from in and outside the campus because of its delicious food and beverages.</p>
            <p>It needs to be emphasized that at the core of the FU Master Plan is the campaign for everyone’s right to quality education. This advocacy, started by Foundation University’s founder Dr. Vicente G. Sinco, has been passed down to each new FU president. It is why FU is proud to be known as a school that caters to students with financial challenges to hurdle as they work towards their educational goals.</p>
        </div>
```

if this work happy

```
https://jsfiddle.net/x0ugLbo4/
```